# How to add a title to a sandbox created in codesandbox with the svelte template

Tags: svelte, codesandbox

I created a svelte project in codesandbox using the svelte client template. When I open the output of the sandbox in its own window, the title is "Sandbox - CodeSandbox".

The default template uses rollup, however it says at the top of the sandbox.config.json file that it won't effect it in the sandbox, and that appears to be correct. There is no existing index.html file either to edit it in.

https://codesandbox.io/s/transformer-svelte-ghtyd?fontsize=14&module=%2FApp.svelte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `public` directory at the root level of your project and add an `index.html` file there. Just make sure to include the JS and CSS bundles that your build will generate.

You can also use `degit` - a scaffolding tool - to start from a template project as explained [here](https://svelte.dev/blog/the-easiest-way-to-get-started#2_Use_degit). This will generate the `public` directory and the `index.html` file, among others, for you.

The template is really very bare bones (a good thing in my opinion). See for yourself:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bundle.css'>

    <script defer src='/bundle.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woo hoo that fixed it! Thanks so much!